# How do I convert an integer from a Typescript enum to its key value as a type of the union of the keys?

Tags: typescript

I have two interfaces in Typescript, one of which uses an enum's integer values, and one of which uses the enum's keys:

```
enum foo {
    bar = 0,
    baz,
}

interface asNumbers {
    qux: foo
}

interface asStrings {
    quux: keyof typeof foo
}
```

I would like to take an object implementing `asNumbers` and convert it to an object implementing `asStrings`.  I have the following code:

```
const numberObject: asNumbers = {
    qux: foo.bar
}

const stringyObject: asStrings = {
    quux: foo[numberObject.qux] 
}
```

I receive the following error though on the stringyObject assignment though.

```
Type '{ quux: string; }' is not assignable to type 'asStrings'.
Types of property 'quux' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"bar" | "baz"'.
```

It is unclear to me how I can take that integer value and convert it into it's key in a typesafe manner (without resorting to more generic `string` types).  Reproducible on typescript playground: [Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%20%3D%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20asNumbers%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20qux%3A%20foo%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20asStrings%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20quux%3A%20keyof%20typeof%20foo%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20numberObject%3A%20asNumbers%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20qux%3A%20foo.bar%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20stringyObject%3A%20asStrings%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20quux%3A%20foo%5BnumberObject.qux%5D%20%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function that provides some type safety while also meeting your use case:

```
const stringyObject: asStrings = {
    quux: getFooProp[numberObject.qux] 
}

function getFooProp(i: foo): (keyof typeof foo) { 
    return foo[i] as (keyof typeof foo);
}
```

If you wanted to be more generic, then you could define a function like this:

```
interface NumericEnum {
    [id: number]: string
}

function getEnumProp<T extends NumericEnum, K extends keyof T>(
    e: T,
    i: T[K]): (keyof T) { 

    return e[i] as (keyof T);
}
```

The compiler helps us in both cases, and will complain when we pass in an enum value that is not of type `foo`.

```
// Works
getEnumProp(foo, foo.bar);

// Argument of type 'foo2.bar' 
// is not assignable to parameter of type 'foo'.
getEnumProp(foo, foo2.bar);
```

[Here is a Fiddle for you](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%20%3D%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20foo2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%20%3D%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getFooProp(i%3A%20foo)%3A%20(keyof%20typeof%20foo)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20foo%5Bi%5D%20as%20(keyof%20typeof%20foo)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20NumericEnum%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bid%3A%20number%5D%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getEnumProp%3CT%20extends%20NumericEnum%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20e%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20i%3A%20T%5BK%5D)%3A%20(keyof%20T)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20e%5Bi%5D%20as%20(keyof%20T)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0AgetEnumProp(foo%2C%20foo.bar)%3B%0D%0AgetFooProp(foo.bar)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Argument%20of%20type%20'foo2.bar'%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'foo'.%0D%0AgetEnumProp(foo%2C%20foo2.bar)%3B%20%0D%0AgetFooProp(foo2.bar)%3B) that demonstrates both.